# Apache2 response Header value clipped when reverse proxy is enabled

Tags: apache, tomcat, http-headers

I have a simple `red.jsp` that does:

```
... 
response.sendRedirect("[test.jsp/VERY_LONG_URL]");
...
```

where `test.jsp` simply prints:

```
...
out.println(request.getParameter("service"));
...
```

In my Tomcat 8.5.23 I have the following configuration in `server.xml`:

```
...
<Connector  port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
            maxHttpHeaderSize="2097152" 
            packetSize="65536"
            connectionTimeout="20000"
            redirectPort="8443" />
....
```

When accessing `localhost:8080/red.jsp` I get the correct output with all my `[VERY_LONG_URL]`.

The output here is **11636 chars** long.

Instead, when accessing `localhost/proxy/red.jsp` using the following httpd proxy configuration:

```
<Location "/proxy">
        ProxyPass         http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:8080/
</Location>
```

the URL is clipped.

The output here is **8228 chars** long.

I have found a related question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/711750/apache-2-4-16-response-header-value-clipped) but I need a solution.

Any workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has already identified a discussion on Serverfault saying that its not possible.

Comment: @symcbean, that thread just says there is a limitation, it does not mean you can't bypass it, so I was hoping to find a workaround. E.g. by editing `mod_proxy.c` and rebuild httpd, but I need help for that.